# Tfidf MemoryError: How to avoid this issue?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-mining, tf-idf

I'm using `scikit-learn` `TfidfVectorizer` to find out the most important words in two documents. Each document is 1.9GB (~90 million words), and already is lower cased, stemmed (using `nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer`) and stopword-free(English stopwords).

I'm using the following code:

```
def simp_tokenizer(text):
    from nltk import word_tokenize

    return word_tokenize(text)

def make_corpus(path):
    from glob import glob
    files = glob(path)

    for doc in files:
        yield open(doc, 'r').read()

def tfidf(path):

    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

    corpus = make_corpus(path = path)
    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(max_features = 500, max_df = 0.8, min_df = 0.2, use_idf = True, tokenizer = simp_tokenizer, analyzer = 'word', ngram_range = (1,1))
    tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(corpus)
    return tfs
```

I have 16GB RAM and after running on 60% usage for a while, raises the MemoryError exception.

I did some research, and incorporated the `make_corpus` function to avoid loading both the documents into the memory at the same time. I also reduced the `max_features` to 500, and `min_df` and `max_df` to 0.2 and 0.8 respectively, as per suggestions on SO and Mark Needham's blog, to get around this problem.

But this Error continues to persist.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: How big are these files? Maybe you should yield also lines of file?

Comment: @frankov About 1.9 GBs each. 90 million words approx. When you say yield these lines the only way I could do that is change the `simp_tokenizer` function. If there's another way, please let me know and I'll try it out.

Comment: if you're on windows and running a 32 bit python - that's your problem, and it does crash at a little less than 2GB usually. you can get more memory available by moving to a 64 bit python.

Comment: @VictorG. I'm actually on Ubuntu Linux 15.10 and running a 64-bit python.

Comment: Yield each line of file instead of yielding whole content of file.

Comment: @frankov I did. Thanks, because that solved the MemoryError problem. However, now I am facing another issue. Because I yielded lines of file, TFIDF is now treating each line as a separate document. I had expected a `2 x n` matrix, each row being the document, `n` being the feature set. But what I am getting is a `15425552 X 4` which is probably sum of lines of the two documents.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @Souradeep I do not have any idea, and I think that TFIDf doesn't treat each line as a separate document.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't impose memory limit beyond what the OS imposes. Make sure you're not limiting the process's memory usage with *ulimit* or equivalent. Also run *top* and see if the process uses all available memory.

How is that your documents near 2GB each? Is it a concatenation of multiple documents? If so, maybe split the documents more.

I would suggest to set-up Spark installation and check the code there. You already have the files, so the only thing that is left is running tfidf part. It has Python interface so it will be fairly painless. Spark is highly optimized for working with big files - may it will overcome scikit-learn's bugs.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.feature import HashingTF
from pyspark.mllib.feature import IDF

sc = SparkContext(...)

# Load documents (one per line).
documents = sc.textFile("...").map(lambda line: line.split(" "))

hashingTF = HashingTF()
tf = hashingTF.transform(documents)

tf.cache()
idf = IDF().fit(tf)
tfidf = idf.transform(tf)
```